# Merging Xbox game data

Tags: xbox-one

I have an Xbox One and I originally created an account under my name. My son is playing Fortnite and I wanted to create his own ID. Can I merge his game data from my account ID to his?

Answer (score 3):

Game data is normally tied to the account, especially if it is an online Game like Fortnite. You can try contacting Epic Games or Microsoft for more advanced support, but there is no user-side settings for account merging.

Answer (score 0):

Fortnite is different, they'll go off your Epic games account. Everything unlocked by that account will transfer over as long as the Epic account ins in place, this also applies to other platforms.

However, there are only a few games like this. So take Rapitor's point as well.